# Running pyspark returns error: ipython not found. (Windows 10)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, windows-10-desktop

getting started with Spark, the setup is done: jdk and python 3.8 are installed and avaible. I can start spark in the shell with using scala aswell. Also in the folder of spark there are datas about pyspark.

But if i want to run pyspark (with writing "pyspark" in the shell) the Error written in the title. (Orginial: Der Befehl "ipython" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.) Translated: The command "ipython" is either written wringly or couldn't be found., appears.

Greeting and thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Translated: "The command "ipython" is either written wrongly or could not be found" (Translated by hand, orginial:  "Der Befehl "ipython" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden")

Comment: Setting environment variables `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/path/to/your/ipython` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/your/python` before starting pyspark can help. `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and  `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` should belong to same python installation. See "launch-ipython.sh" script in https://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2018/08/11/setup-spark-cluster-on-aws-emr/.

Comment: I did it and the same error appears.